# App Engine latency while in the middle of a request processing

Tags: google-app-engine, latency

Why would there be any latency in App Engine in the middle of processing a request? 
This only happens at times and randomly occurs at different places in the request handling with a latency of around 3 or more seconds after starting to process a request.
 [image: gae logs for latency]

Comment: Can you show the handler code?

Answer (score 1):

The usual suspect is your handler reaching out for some resources, either from GAE APIs (datastore, memcache, etc), other GCP API/infra (cloud storage, machine learning, big query, etc) or an external/3rd party service/URL.

Most, if not all such interactions can occasionally encounter peak response times way longer than average for various possible reasons (or combinations of reasons), for example:

- temporary outages of the service being accessed of in the networking layer ensuring connectivity to them
- retries at networking or application layers due to communication errors/packet loss
- service VMs/instances needed to be launched from scratch during (re)starts or even during scaling up
- normal operation conditions which require more time, like datastore transaction retries due to collisions

If the occurrence rate becomes unacceptable an investigation would need to be done to identify which of such external accesses is/are responsible, what are the conditions causing them and maybe find some solution to prevent or reduce the impact of the occurences.

Of course, there may be other reasons as well.